# Spring Hibernate - Self joined many-to-many entity can't be updated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to add a `comment` to a parent if it belongs to it. `Comment` is a self joined many-to-many entity, as attached below.

In this function, I'm trying to find if a `Comment` belongs to a parent, by searching if it has a `parentId` through `getParentId()`.

If it's not null, there must be a parent, therefore, find this parent, and add this `comment` instance as one of the `subComment` set of the parent.

I can't seem to properly persist the newly added subcomments.

```
public ResponseEntity<Comment> addComment(Comment comment) {
    Comment newComment = commentRepository.save(comment);

    if (newComment.getParentId() != null) {
        Comment parent = commentRepository.findById(newComment.getParentId()).orElse(null);
        if (parent != null) {
            Set<Comment> parentSubcComment = parent.getSubComments();
            parentSubcComment.add(newComment);
            parent.setSubComments(parentSubcComment);
            commentRepository.save(parent);
        }
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(newComment);
}
```

Comment.java entity class

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    private String text;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createDateTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentComment")
    private Set<Comment> subComments = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Comment parentComment;

    private int likeCount = 0;
    private boolean isParent;
    private String parentId;

    public String getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public Set<Comment> getSubComments() {
        return subComments;
    }

    public void setSubComments(Set<Comment> subComments) {
        this.subComments = subComments;
    }

    public Comment getParentComment() {
        return parentComment;
    }

    public void setParentComment(Comment parentComment) {
        this.parentComment = parentComment;
    }

    public boolean getIsParent() {
        return isParent;
    }

    public void setIsParent(boolean isParent) {
        this.isParent = isParent;
    }

    public int getLikeCount() {
        return likeCount;
    }

    public void incLikeCount() {
        this.likeCount++;
    }

    public String getCreateDateTime() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy @ hh:mm a");
        return createDateTime.format(formatter);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + id + " text: " + text + " isParent: " + isParent + " parentId: " + parentId;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a `name` for a `parentComment` property in a `@JoinColumn`? Now it is looks like a default - Id. Try to Add `@JoinColumn(name = "parentId")`

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov I don't think I understand your question. I think it's just default right now, if you're asking for the name of the join column.

Comment: I think design is not good here, for adding a subcomment you are querying from db for existing subcomments then adding new comment as subcomment. What happened if there are lots of subcomments?

Comment: @GauravSrivastav Are you saying that using `setSubComments` is bad? If so, I can easily add a method that adds a new `Comment`. I understand that the design is probably bad, but my immediate problem is I can't update my db after I've added a new commet

Comment: What exactly error  you are getting?

Comment: no errors. Just that when I do a get request on Postman, I see an empty `subComments`

Answer (score 0):

You should update the entity for parentComment and add cascade property.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Comment parentComment;
```

Comment: Can you explain how cascade helps with updating? I tried it and it's still the same, empty `subComments`